# Can a bail enforcement agent be assigned as a bodyguard?

Tags: employment

So I looked it up and google did a great job... of not answering my question. I am helping develop this game. It is going to be a very realistic game, however what I want to know is, can a bail enforcement agent be assigned as a bodyguard since bail agents are trained in the similar skill set as a bodyguard?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a legal question - but instead asks about the overlapping skillsets of two professions (one of which is tangentially connected to law enforcement).

Comment: It seems far more likely that OP already understands the overlap between the two skill sets and is instead asking whether there are any *legal* restrictions on a person holding both positions.

Comment: ohwilleke has once again surprised me with a good legal answer to a question that I didn't think would have one.  I'm voting to leave open on that basis, since clearly the question was in fact answerable from a legal perspective.  (Rock Ape's is good as well)

Comment: @RyanM having read the answers I find myself agreeing with you.. VTC retracted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most jurisdictions don't require special licensure for bodyguards and don't regulate it as a profession or occupation. Body guards in those jurisdictions don't have any special legal authority or any special legal responsibilities other than a fiduciary duty to protect the client. They have the same rights to make citizens arrests and carry weapons that any ordinary citizen would.

If a jurisdiction does regulate bodyguards, the answer depends upon the law of the jurisdiction which varies considerably.

Only a minority of jurisdictions in the world even recognize the concept of cash bond, or the concept of a bail enforcement agent.

Logically, it is unlikely that the regulation of bail enforcement agents in places where bail bonds exist is unlikely to be the same as that of a bodyguard.

A bail enforcement agent's authority flows from the adjudication of a court that a particular person has diminished rights while on bail, and that the bail bonding company through its bail enforcement agent, has extraordinary authority (analogous to that of a parent or legal guardian) over that particular person for whom the bail bond agency has taken responsibility. A bail enforcement agent doesn't have special authority over anyone else as a general rule.

In contrast, a bodyguard is generally seeking to protect one person from the entire rest of the world, when the entire rest of the world is not subject to any court orders temporarily diminishing their rights. So, it wouldn't make sense for a bail enforcement agent to have the same legal treatment as a bodyguard, even if both were regulated occupations or professions. A body guard is more analogous to a private security guard for a business, or premises, or vehicle, which a minority of jurisdictions regulate as a licensed occupation or profession.

Of course, if the skills and qualifications for both bail enforcement agents and bodyguards are similar in a jurisdiction where both profession or occupations are regulated, nothing would prevent the same individual from obtaining both kinds of licenses.

In your fictional world, however, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Why would they owe their client a “fiduciary” rather than just a contractural duty?

Comment: @DaleM Usually duties in which one person is entrusting their property or life to another are fiduciary in nature. See also, doctors and trustees. When something that is your in the hands of another it is usually fiduciary. When someone is just doing something for you in exchange for money that doesn't involve your property or life, it is usually contractual.

Answer (score 2):

**Can a bail enforcement agent be assigned as a bodyguard?**

### [england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

Generally, there are very few embargos on having more than one job at any one time, but there may be some contractual restriction if, say, an employer or trade association identifies a potential conflict of interest.

Bodyguards are [regulated](https://www.gov.uk/close-protection-licence) and require a Close Protection Licence issued by the [Security Industry Authority](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Industry_Authority).

The procedures for dealing with breaches of bail are different than some other jurisdictions and dealt by the police. Probably the nearest role to an American bail bondsman is a [bailiff](https://www.gov.uk/your-rights-bailiffs) or [certified enforcement agent](https://certificatedbailiffs.justice.gov.uk/#:%7E:text=This%20register%20holds%20details%20of,these%20to%20recover%20a%20debt.); both of whom require certification to operate lawfully.